# I have following errors even though i have updated java and new version of chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 44837
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Mar 28, 2023 11:23:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:50470/devtools/browser/75186f31-5807-45fe-ae39-8f17f04766df
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at rahulshetty.Test_automation.main(Test_automation.java:17)
```

I tried installing new chrome driver and setting automatic chrome setup but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
 
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

In the latest chrome version occurs this issues, By adding this argument `--remote-allow-origins=*` your problem will solved